# How to pass all the values in an array which is processed by for loop?

Tags: php

```
<?php

    $xml = simplexml_load_file("sample.xml");

    echo " ". $xml->getName() . "<br />";

    foreach($xml->children()->children() as $child)

      {

      $a=$child->getName() . "<br />";
        array_push($a);
        echo $a;

      }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
    $arr = array();        
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("sample.xml");

    echo " ". $xml->getName() . "<br />";

    foreach($xml->children()->children() as $child)
    {
        $a=$child->getName() . "<br />";
        $arr[] = $a;
        echo $a;
    }
?>
```

Comment: thank you. it returns catalog
author
title
genre
price
publish_date
description. Now i want to fetch the first name i.e author. but by using $a[0] it returns first letter of all the child name i.e atgppd. how i get the first child name?

Comment: I didn't get you? You need more values in the array or anything else?

Comment: No. i want to fetch the first value i.e author from the array.

Comment: @chetannaik I am sorry I am not able to understand can you edit your question with the whole code?

Comment: What i am saying is after executing the above code the array $a has some values i.e author, title, gene...Now i want to fetch the first value i.e 'author' from array. so i use $a[0]. but it returns the first alphabet of all the values from array i.e 'a''t''g'. what should i do to fetch the first value?

Comment: @chetannaik Can you paste the data in the same format you're getting after parsing from xml file? I need to see what data you're trying to store it in the array. Whats is the value `$child->getName()` of this expression? & also the array variable is `$arr` not `$a` when you use `$a` with an index like `echo $a[0]` it will treat the string `$a` as an array of words so the result you're getting is right. for the full word you will use `$arr[0]`.

Comment: Thank you rohit now i got it. i thought $a is the array name.

Comment: @chetannaik Ok! Close the question if your problem has been solved.